# Canvas with moving bubbles over a blurred div

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas, blur

I have a canvas which has bubbles moving randomly, now when i put it on to a div which has a filter

```
    -webkit-filter: blur(50px);
```

then the canvas bubble movement fps drops down and smoothness reduces.

I am not getting what is the issue.

Version with blurred background : http://freakengineers.com/bubbles/index.php

Version with normal background  : http://freakengineers.com/bubbles/index2.php

Comment: `blur` is a very expensive operation which requires multiple comparisons of neighboring pixels. Instead of having the client apply the blur, just blur the image before you send it to the client in your favorite image editor: Photoshop, Gimp, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can load and blur the image (but I don't know if you can use a built in blur algorithm - I've used [StackBlur](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html)) in a separate canvas as a sort of buffer, then copy it to your main canvas on each frame. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1m8rbt7j/

Add a new `<canvas>` element to the HTML, load your image into it and then blur the new canvas:

```
var blurimg = new Image();

blurimg.onload = function() {
  var blurcv = document.getElementById('blurcanvas');
  blurcv.getContext('2d').drawImage(blurimg,0,0);
  stackBlurCanvasRGB('blurcanvas', 0, 0, 1580, 730, 50);
};

blurimg.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/WaMsYBC.jpg';
```

(I had to use a different image to get around cross-origin rules.)

Then just draw the content of the new canvas to your main canvas at the start of each frame:

```
context.clearRect(0,0, w,h);
context.drawImage(document.getElementById('blurcanvas'),0,0);
```

With your versions I get 30 FPS without the blur and 20 FPS with it. I get 30 FPS with the blur in my version.

Comment: Just informals: You can also use my [realtime-blur](https://github.com/epistemex/realtime-blur-js) which gets around CORS restrictions (and uses HW-accelleration if available). Next generation canvas will come with a `filter` attribute that can take css-filters directly. For now manually blurring is required, or separate image (latter with higher loading cost but less performance cost). Imgur do support CORS btw; just add `blurimg.crossOrigin = "";` before setting src.